Using bitmap index in oracle db when many inserts/updates in single thread mode
I have a question about using bitmap indexes in oracle...
Context: my app is analyst system with too many reads to view calculated stats in web app. Data is loading to db in singlethread mode from one microservice, which reads events from queue.. events - 500k per day (approximately) and average speed about 20rps
Problem: various sql queries are used to calculate statistics and performance is low.. I try to speed up performance using btree index but unsuccessfully.. queries take tens seconds to complete..
I consider to use bitmap index to improve permormance..  could you advice me some practice about it... I read a lot of docs about bitmap indexes, about concurent transactions... and problems.. but i have single thread mode..  maybe someone faced with the same problem..  will i have problems or not if i start using bitmap..

Thanks everybody for advice
What I did.

created several bitmap indexes on a table
change architecture of data processing to minimize problem with bitmap indexes
You can watch final architecture below


This architecture helps me to solve two problem:

minimize concurrent transations on write
unified processing of all events from different sources


In general bitmap indexes are used for columns with low cardinality, i.e. low number of distinct values (compared to total number of records in your table/partition)
In many examples you see index like this:
CREATE BITMAP INDEX IND_GENDER ON EMP (GENDER);

Usually you have only two different values for GENDER, e.g. male and female (nowadays maybe a little more).
However, having a table with just one bitmap index does not make much sense. Typical use-case is to have multiple bitmap indexes and your typical query has condition on multiple columns. A single bitmap indexes does not make your query selective, but the combination of multiple columns makes the query selective and fast.
Hint: Maybe your requirement is to have an index on a DATE column with many different values. A bitmap index does not make much sense, however you can create the bitmap indexes for example on day and month value, e.g.
CREATE BITMAP INDEX IND_END_TIME_MONTH ON ROUTES (TRUNC(END_TIME, 'MM')); 
CREATE BITMAP INDEX IND_END_TIME_DAY ON ROUTES (TO_CHAR(END_TIME, 'DD')); 

Of course, you must adapt your query accordingly to enable Oracle using the indexes.
Yes, bitmap indexes can cause issues in a multi-user environment, more precisely if multiple users make updates/inserts into the same table/partition. This topic does not seem to be a problem in your case.
Another issue are modifications. Bitmap indexes do not index the records one by one, the index values are done on blocks. When you update/insert/delete a record then the index value is calculated for an entire block rather than just for the single record.
When you insert your data, then the preferred way is to insert the data into a TEMP table then use
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE ROUTES_TEMP (...)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO ROUTES_TEMP (...) VALUES (...);
INSERT INTO ROUTES_TEMP (...) VALUES (...);
INSERT INTO ROUTES_TEMP (...) VALUES (...);

INSERT INTO ROUTES (...)
SELECT ... 
FROM ROUTES_TEMP;

Bulk inserts may also work, but I did not test it. Or you can deal with EXCHANGE PARTITION. Some guidelines even suggest to truncate the entire table and insert all data at once every time you like to add new data. But I think in many cases this is not practical.
